# Build error when using sympy with esky

Tags: python, py2exe, cx-freeze, sympy, esky

I encounter the following error when freezing an app with esky. This occurs when using py2exe as the freezer module.

```
error: c:\docume~1\user\locals~1\temp\tmpkizl0t\scripts\my_script.py:
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

The error only occurs when I use the sympy module in my code and add it to the packages in my setup.py file.
Here is the "options" part of my setup.py file:

```
options = {
           'bdist_esky': {"freezer_module":"py2exe",
              'includes':['encodings','Symbolic','matplotlib','Sequence','ClientTCP',
                          'XMLSequenceParser','XMLSequenceWriter','utils.widgets',
                          'pylab','ConfigParser','numpy','xml.etree.ElementTree','logging',
                          're','json','pylab','socket','struct','threading','traceback',
                          'utils.liststore','Reporter','tempfile', 'filecmp','os',  
                          'cairo', 'pango', 'pangocairo', 'atk', 'gobject', 'gio','matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg','sympy'],
              }
          },
```

Problem below solved by answer from Thomas K:

If I use cx_freeze as the freezer module then the build completes but when I try to run the executable I get a similar error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cx_Freeze__init__.py", line 743, in <module>
File "cx_Freeze__init__.py", line 332, in bootstrap
File "cx_Freeze__init__.py", line 359, in chainload
File "cx_Freeze__init__.py", line 729, in _chainload
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27
, in <module>
exec code in m.__dict__
File "c:\docume~1\user\locals~1\temp\tmpyisdxd\scripts\my_script.py", line 1447,
in <module>
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

Has anyone come across this problem?

Comment: I don't think you can use `__file__` in frozen applications, because it's not actually running from a script file.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this is the answer to the problem when using cx_freeze as the freezer module. The error when using py2exe remains, but at least I can freeze it with cx_freeze.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate that some other process is using one of the SymPy files. Maybe just restarting the computer will fix it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but restarting does not help. I've also tried using a different computer, with the same result.